# How many integers $n$ greater than $2$ are there such that the degree measure of each interior angle of a regular $n$-gon is an even integer?

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, elementary-number-theory

> How many integers $n$ greater than $2$ are there such that the degree measure of each interior angle of a regular $n$-gon is an even integer?

I know that the degree measure of an interior angle in an $n$-gon is derived using the formula $\frac{(n-2)\cdot180}{n}$, but I'm not sure how to get that value to be an *even* integer. I split $180$ into $2$ and $90$, and the prime factorization of $90$ is $2\cdot3^2\cdot5$, and this has $2\cdot3\cdot2$ factors, or $12$, to be exact. This is how far I have gotten to, how can I proceed?

Comment: Note $\frac{(n-2)\cdot 180}{n} = \frac{180n - 360}{n} = 180 - \frac{360}{n}$.

Comment: @John Omielan thank you for the help! I think I understand now.

Answer (score 3):

The degree measure of an interior angle of a regular polygon with $n$ sides is
$$\frac{180(n - 2)}{n} = \frac{180n - 360}{n} = 180 - \frac{360}{n}$$
This expression will yield an even number provided that $n$ is a factor of $360$ and $360/n$ is not odd.

Since $360 = 2^3 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 5$, it has $(3 + 1)(2 + 1)(1 + 1) = 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 = 24$ factors. Observe that if $n$ is a factor of $360$, $360/n$ will be even unless $n$ is a multiple of $2^3 = 8$.  There are $1 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 = 6$ such multiples, leaving us with $24 - 6 = 18$ candidates.  However, two of these are $1$ and $2$, and a polygon must have at least three sides.  Hence, there are $16$ possible values of $n$ such that the degree measure of each interior angle of a regular polygon with $n$ sides is even.

Answer (score 0):

$\displaystyle \frac{(n-2)180}{n} = 2k \implies $

$\displaystyle (n-2)180 = 2nk \implies $

$\displaystyle (n)(180 - 2k) = 360 \implies $

$\displaystyle (n)(90 - k) = 180$.

Since $180 = 2^2 \times 3^2 \times 5$, you have that

$180$ has $3 \times 3 \times 2 = 18$ divisors, including the numbers $1$ and $180$.  However, the values of $n=1$ and $n=2$ must be rejected, since you can not have a polygon with less than $3$ sides.

Each such divisor $n$, where $n \geq 3$, will yield a positive integer value of $k$ such that

$$(n)(90 - k) = 180.$$

Therefore, there must be exactly $16$ distinct satisfying values for $n$.

Comment: There are actually $16$ such values of $n$: $3, 4, 5, 6, 9, 10, 12, 15, 18, 20, 30, 36, 45, 60, 90, 180$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Who knew that $(3 \times 3 \times 2) = 18~$?